# personalize asp.net membership - basic

Tags: asp.net, membership

I am interested in adding some more data to users (like Real name), making the email a nonmandatory field, and telephone mandatory when registering. Is this possible? How?

I'm using forms authentication
Thanks, this should be easy, but I found no example on this topic

Comment: Check this: http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-vb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly possible, there's a walkthrough [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx)